# Async controllers dont get looping/dont get called

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous

I recently tried "updating" my controllers to use async methods.
Now everytime that I try to access anything that has an async in its signature it just keeps on loading never endlessly

As an example here is a controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
    _usersLogic = new UsersLogic(User.Identity.Name);
    return View(await _usersLogic.get());
}
```

The function that is getting called if you want to assume that the problem is in my code

```
private string user;

public UsersLogic(user)
{
    this.user = user;
}

public async Task<Agent> Get()
{
    return await Context.Users.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.ID == user);
}
```

What could be causing this? Some kind of assemblies that have gone wrong?
What is this magic that makes my threads wait forever?

Comment: This code seems incorrect, in particular that last return statement is missing an end parenthesis. Can you ensure you got the right code copied into the question?

Comment: You are using Wait or Result somewhere. Audit the code for that.

Comment: Thats right. I changed the code a little bit (it was written agent and user originally not just user) to make it less confusing to read. Whats the problem with Result?

Comment: @misha130: http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: @misha130 How can we help you when you're not posting the actual piece of code causing you trouble?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using `Result` in a piece of code not shown here. [This causes a deadlock in ASP.NET.](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)

Comment: That is a whole new level of psychic debugging capabilities. Do you get that with 90k+ rep? :P